# Accessing an Excel object created by win32com with xlwings or openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl, win32com, xlwings

I'm attempting to write a script that needs to access an Excel workbook containing many external references to other Excel workbooks.  The script should be inventorying the cells in each worksheet of the main workbook containing a reference, copying pertinent information (Worksheet, cell coordinate, formula, computed value) to a pandas dataframe.

I start my script by using win32com to create an Excel app instance where DisplayAlerts and Update Links are already off.  These two settings interfere with openpyxl and xlwings in my scenario.

Is it possible to access the active Excel workbook launched by win32com in the active Excel application, using either the xlwings or openpyxl packages?

Suppose I create a workbook object named win32_wb using the following code:

```
import xlwings as xw
import openpyxl
import win32com.client as win32
from win32com.client import DispatchEx
import pandas as pd

file_1 = r"C:\Users\me\Documents\ext_ref.xlsx"

# Create an instance of Excel
excel_1 = win32.DispatchEx('Excel.Application')

# Ensure the Excel instance is not shown in the U/I (runs faster)
excel_1.Visible = False

# disable Warning & Link Update messages for excel_1
run_macro(excel_1)

# Open the ref workbook as an object in the Excel instance  
wb = excel_1.workbooks.open(file_1)

# Need to access the object with openpyxl or xlwings
```

Comment: You can't do this with openpyxl but xlwings should work.

Comment: You can do all of the above with xlwings, see also https://github.com/ZoomerAnalytics/xlwings/issues/562 for Link Update messages. If you'd like to leave your code as is, you can access the open book like so: `xw.Book(file_1)`